# PHP error when using newer PHP versions

Tags: php

When enabling PHP version 7.2.17 or newer on my site, I get a PHP-related error message on some pages.

**Warning:** Use of undefined constant comment_notes_before - assumed 'comment_notes_before' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in **/home/(username)/public_html/(domain name).com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child/comments.php** on line **68**

Here is the code on line 68 of the comments.php file:

```
comment_form( array( 'fields' => $fields, 'label_submit' => esc_attr__( 'Submit', 'Divi' ), 'title_reply' => '<span>' . esc_attr__( 'Leave a comment', 'Divi' ) . '</span>', 'title_reply_to' => esc_attr__( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'Divi' ), 'class_submit' => 'submit et_pb_button', comment_notes_before
```

And here is line 69:

```
=>'<p class="comment-notes">' . __( '' ) . '</p>' ) ); ?>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this and what adjustments I need to make to the PHP source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change that line to

```
comment_form( array( 'fields' => $fields, 'label_submit' => esc_attr__( 'Submit', 'Divi' ), 'title_reply' => '<span>' . esc_attr__( 'Leave a comment', 'Divi' ) . '</span>', 'title_reply_to' => esc_attr__( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'Divi' ), 'class_submit' => 'submit et_pb_button', 'comment_notes_before'
```

Comment: You are welcome. Seams that your issue is not in the PHP version, it is because this line of the source code is not finished.

Comment: I'm getting an error related to line 69 now! I will update my question so you can see line 69 of the comments.php file. New error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in /home/(username)/public_html/(domain name).com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child/comments.php on line 69

Comment: Can you please make a screenshot of the whole file or 10-20 lines of the source code, please. Or you can try to change 68 line to this comment_form( array( 'fields' => $fields, 'label_submit' => esc_attr__( 'Submit', 'Divi' ), 'title_reply' => '<span>' . esc_attr__( 'Leave a comment', 'Divi' ) . '</span>', 'title_reply_to' => esc_attr__( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'Divi' ), 'class_submit' => 'submit et_pb_button', 'comment_notes_before'

Comment: That fixed it! Can you update your answer? I'll mark it as official. All that was needed was quotation marks around 'comment_notes_before' 

Comment: Changed, thanks.